# Cygwin- Trying to run DOS command in C language

Tags: c, cygwin, system, popen

I have tried both `system()` and `popen()`. When I run the program on cygwin terminal it works perfectly fine but when I try to run it on windows platform by double clicking on .exe file I get this error:
`exception::handle: Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION`
I get this error on `popen()` however I do not get any error for `system()`.

I am running simple commands that work on both unix and windows OSs such as:

`system("echo foo>foo.txt");`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is your path environment variable the same?

Comment: There is no environment variable.

Comment: there is always an environment variable

Comment: I meant I haven't specified anything. How do I change or see it?

Answer (score 2):

I think that's because both `system()` and `popen()` pass their arguments to the `/bin/sh` which you don't have in the path, you could try adding it to the path first. According to [this](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2011-07/msg00230.html) you need the following in your path:

```
cyggcc_s-1.dll
cygiconv-2.dll 
cygintl-8.dll 
cygncursesw-10.dll 
cygreadline7.dll 
cygwin1.dll
ls.exe 
sh.exe
```

Comment: he's using Cygwin, so there is `echo` in both `/bin` and `system32`. Obviously its that both are not set. Or there is a different error.

Comment: @Aniket yes but there's no sh.exe in the path, see man system

Comment: that's correct. Manpages say a lot. People should read them before asking a question. +1

Comment: How can I add it to the path?

Comment: I have these files in the same directory as my .exe program I still get the same error.

Comment: @SarpKaya they need to be added to the PATH variable.

Comment: try this on windows : system("cmd /c \"echo foo>foo.txt\"");

Comment: @mux : On Windows, they does not have to be in PATH if they are in same directory as executable. Read this first : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @rkosegi not the dlls maybe, but the sh.exe needs to be in the PATH, and it requires the dlls, read the link included in my answer.

Comment: @mux : OP mention that all files listed (including exe) are in same directory as his program.so DLL search order are applied here also for exe.Maybe dependancy problem.

Comment: @mux I am sorry, I have done it by `strcpy(PATH,"bin/");` but compiler says that PATH variable has not declared(I have googled and found that there is a PATH variable but I cannot change it???)

Comment: @SarpKaya : Start -> run -> sysdm.cpl -> Advanced -> Environment Variables -> Look for PATH and edit it

Comment: @rkosegi I think that's not the case for `system()` and `pope()` they use the PATH to look for sh.exe otherwise it would have worked.

Comment: Okay, that shows as Windows/System32
and I have copied every file into that folder.

Still getting the same error...

Comment: @mux on windows system() and popen() are implemented by CRT using CreateProcess system call : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx same condition applied.

Comment: @rkosegi yes but those are cygwin's versions of `system()` and `popen()` :)

Comment: @mux cygwin use same system calls on underlaying module implemented in cygwin1.dll.These systems calls are exposed from KERNEL32.DLL and you can check it using tools like depends.exe

Comment: @rkosegi even so, it tries to execute `/bin/sh` not `sh` or `./sh`, i.e not a relative path, so `bin` needs to be in the path, maybe that's why it fails

Comment: @mux It actually works like that, but, however I would like to install this to other computers without actually installing the whole bin folder. Is there a way?

Comment: @SarpKaya I'm not sure but maybe you could use `exec()` to execute the shell and pass the arguments yourself instead of `system()`.